# ngx-datatable - custom columns with action buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-datatable, viewchild, ng-template

I have a table ([ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable)) in which I want to define an "actions" column in which buttons will then be placed for CRUD operations.

Creating the column and placing the buttons worked, but I have the problem that the selected row and the values ​​in its columns are no longer recognized inside my triggered function.

Here is my template:

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <ngx-datatable
    #table
    class="material"
    [rowHeight]="'auto'"
    [columns]="columns"
    [columnMode]="'force'"
    [headerHeight]="50"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    [limit]="10"
    [rows]="cars?.content"
    [selected]="selected"
    [selectionType]="'multi'">
  </ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

Here is my custom template with the buttons:

```html
<ng-template #buttonsTemplate let-row="row" let-value="value" let-button="column.actions">
  <button class="btn btn-transparent" (click)='onSelect($event)'><i class="rb-ic rb-ic-add-frame"></i></button>
  <button class="btn bt n-transparent" (click)='onSelect($event)><i class="rb-ic rb-ic-abort-frame"></i></button>
  <button class="btn btn-transparent" (click)='onSelect($event)><i class="rb-ic rb-ic-reset"></i></button>
  <button class="btn btn-transparent" (click)='onSelect($event)><i class="rb-ic rb-ic-agility"></i></button>
</ng-template>
```

My component (.ts file) is structured like this:

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('buttonsTemplate') buttonsTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  columns = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.columns = [
    {prop: 'id', name: 'Id'},
    {prop: 'serial_number', name: 'Serial Number'},
    {prop: 'actions', name: 'Actions', cellTemplate: this.buttonsTemplate}
    ];
  }

  // This method should be called after clicking an action button
  onSelect({selected}) {
    console.log('Array of selected vehicles', selected);
  }
}
```

Currently this error occurs in the console:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'serial_number'
>   of undefined

What am I doing wrong? The [official documentation](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/) and [demo page](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/) doesn't helped me..

---

Approach from @wentjun (not working: button not visibile inside column)

The Template:

```html
<ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index;" name="{{column.name}}" prop="{{column.prop}}">
  <ng-template #buttonsTemplate let-row="row" let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
    <button class="btn btn-transparent" (click)='onSelect(row)'><i class="rb-ic rb-ic-add-frame"></i></button>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

The Component (function):

```js
onSelect({selected}) {
  console.log('Array of selected vehicles', selected);
}
```

Comment: can you please post the response json (cars content) you are trying to populate

Comment: You mean --> {id: "5cfa46bc934b930018e66c", serial_number: "Tx2dh2"}

Comment: and It's structured like this --> content: (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Answer (score 8):

I am using the `ngx-datatable` library, and I have a similar setup to your project, thus I believe I see where your problem is coming from.

If your `<ng-template>` is not nested within the `<ngx-datatable-column>`,you should put it within it. In addition, on your `click` event binding, you should be passing the `row` values into your `onSelect()` methods, since you are trying to access the row data. You will need to use the `ngx-datatable-cell-template` directive within your `<ng-template>` too.

This are the changes you should be making:

```html
<ngx-datatable 
[rows]="rows" 
class="material" 
[loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
[columnMode]="'force'" 
[headerHeight]="50" 
[footerHeight]="50" 
[rowHeight]="'auto'"
[columns]="columns" 
[reorderable]="reorderable">

  <ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index;" name="{{column.name}}" prop="{{column.prop}}">
    <ng-template let-value="value" let-row="row" *ngIf="column.name==='Actions'" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
      <span>
        <button style="background-color:red;height:15px;" (click)='onSelectRed(row)'><i class="rb-ic rb-ic-add-frame"></i></button>
        <button style="background-color:blue;height:15px;" class="btn" (click)='onSelectBlue(value)'><i class="rb-ic rb-ic-add-frame"></i></button>
      </span>
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

And on your component.ts, you should be able to access the data of the entire row, or the value of the property itself, depending on the value you have binded on the click method.

```js
onSelectRed(row) {
  console.log(row);
}

onSelectBlue(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

I have created a demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-fkodb4?file=app/app.component.html). As you can see, the values of `row` and the binded property (`id`) can be accessed within the row buttons itself.

Comment: I've updated my question with your approach. Now the buttons are no longer visible inside the columns..

Comment: Hi, I must apologise, for I wasn't very clear with my explanation. I have created a demo, and added more details in the code on my answer. Hope it clears things up for you.

Comment: I have copied your code exactly line by line, I thought it may be some mistakes, but not worked for me. I don't know how, exact same is working when I modify your slackblitz code. Please point me to some link, I am not able to perform crud operation in my application.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let column of columns' >
            <ngx-datatable-column *ngIf='column.name === "Actions"' name="Actions" prop="actions">
                <ng-template let-value="value" let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    <span>
                        <button class='btn btn-icon icon-left'>
                            Continue
                            <i [ngClass]='row.actions.continue'></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class='btn btn-icon icon-left'>
                            Remove
                            <i [ngClass]='row.actions.delete'></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
            <ngx-datatable-column *ngIf='column.name !== "Actions"' name="{{column.name}}" prop="{{column.prop}}">
            </ngx-datatable-column>
        </ng-container>
```

OP wentjun's solution works better with an ng-container in Angular 10+.

Answer (score 1):

Credits to [@m4limo](https://github.com/m4limo)

(I added my own observations)

---

## Original comment

just use the `ng-tamplate`:

```html
<ngx-datatable-column name="Actions" sortable="false" prop="id">
      <ng-template let-row="row" let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>

            <button md-icon-button (click)="blockAgents(value)">
              <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
            </button>

            <button md-icon-button (click)="approveAgent(value)">
              <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            </button>

      </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

`value` corresponds to the property `prop` you define in `ngx-datatable-column`, in this case `id`

---

### Observations

You need to declare the column prop name inside the `prop` property of the `ngx-datatable-column` element, `let-value` will assign the property to a variable, in this case, named "value", which will be assigned/used in your `ng-template` child object.

"value" will get the property value from your row (object listed) using the column `prop` value. The column prop name **NEED** to match with a property of the row object.

### Notes

- Tested in Angular 9.1.1 (using Ivy)
- Using @swimlane/ngx-datatable 16.0.3

Original GitHub comment [here](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/489#issuecomment-356765048)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `row` instead of `$event` on click.

```
<ng-template #buttonsTemplate let-row="row" let-value="value">
  <button class="btn btn-transparent" (click)='onSelect(row)'><i class="rb-ic rb-ic-add-frame"></i></button>
  <button class="btn bt n-transparent" (click)='onSelect(row)><i class="rb-ic rb-ic-abort-frame"></i></button>
  <button class="btn btn-transparent" (click)='onSelect(row)><i class="rb-ic rb-ic-reset"></i></button>
  <button class="btn btn-transparent" (click)='onSelect(row)><i class="rb-ic rb-ic-agility"></i></button>
</ng-template>
```

and in the `onSelect` function, you will be able to access the row details.

```
onSelect(row) { 
  console.log(row); 
}
```

Please find the working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-responsive-demo-fc3shs?file=app%2Fdemo-component.ts)